# "em is not defined error" when trying to run doctrine command

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I've just setup a ZF2 project and configured it all for Doctrine2 without issue. It works and simply gives me an error now as it cannot find the database table I am trying to query.

Entity is also setup correctly, all as per http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

So wanted to use the CLI to create the tables etc but when running any CLI command I get

```
[InvalidArgumentException]       
The helper "em" is not defined.
```

Command I am using

```
php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

Am running the doctrine.php from folder

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/zf2-Skel-NewProj1/vendor/bin
```

Now if I use the CLI for one of my ZF1.11 projects it works fine.

To get this working do I have to edit the cli-config.php file located under

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/zf2-Skel-NewProj1/vendor/doctrine/orm/tools
```

Contents of this file is:

```
<?php

require_once '../../lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\ORM', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\DBAL', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../lib/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../lib/vendor'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(__DIR__."/Entities"));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

$connectionOptions = array(
'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
'path' => 'database.sqlite'
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql

Comment: php doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql worked. Nice would have though it would have matched the old ZF1 way of running it. 

Many thanks Zdenek.